# preg_replace and remainder of string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to do a `preg_replace` to replace everything in between `SELECT` and `FROM` with `COUNT(id)` like so:

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT dogs,cats,birds,id FROM animals WHERE claws="no"';

$count_sql = preg_replace("/[^SELECT ](.*)[^ FROM]/","COUNT(id)",$sql);

echo $count_sql;
```

What I want returned is:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM animals WHERE claws="no"
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
```

I'm a regex noob and I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Thank you!

Comment: What did you mean `[^SELECT]` and `[^FROM]` to do?

Comment: I'm trying to replace everything in between `SELECT` and `FROM` with `COUNT(id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't place words inside of a character class `[]` at all, even trying to negate them. You could do this using a combination of a **Positive Lookbehind** and **Negative Lookahead**.

```
$count_sql = preg_replace('/(?<=SELECT)((?!FROM).)*/',' COUNT(id) ', $sql);
```

Or even a combination of a **Positive Lookbehind** and **Positive Lookahead**

```
$count_sql = preg_replace('/(?<=SELECT).*?(?=FROM)/',' COUNT(id) ', $sql);
```

Or you could go the simple route by capturing `SELECT` and `FROM` and replacing everything between.

```
$count_sql = preg_replace('/(SELECT).*?(FROM)/','$1 COUNT(id) $2', $sql);
```

For explanation on how these regular expressions work, visit [Explain Regular Expression](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=) and input them.

Comment: awesome, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Do they both do the same thing? Is there an advantage of one solution over the other?

Comment: Updated answer with a link for regular expression explanations.

Comment: Thanks, I inputted them into your link and for the second solution I don't understand why it doesn't stop after it finds `FROM` ... if it is easy to explain I'd appreciate it, otherwise thanks for your time already!

Comment: The second one finds everything after `SELECT` and looks ahead to find `FROM`.

Comment: One question - what if there was a line break `\n` between SELECT and FROM - how would I also match that?

Comment: You could use the `s` modifier which makes the dot match newline as well

Answer (score 1):

Rather than complicating the regex to include negative matches, just include the unchanged parts in the replacement:

```
 $count_sql = preg_replace("/(SELECT ).*( FROM)/","$1COUNT(id)$2",$sql);
```

Or even simpler:

```
 $count_sql = preg_replace("/SELECT .* FROM/","SELECT COUNT(id) FROM",$sql);
```

**Edit:** Since you're throwing away the old text, you don't need to capture it in brackets.